# Static image file is invisible in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloud9-ide

The following code is an exemple of code to serve static files in express on node.js. If I ask the server a .css file there is no problem, but if I ask an image such as a jpg or png, it loads a white page (no /GET error or anything, a simple white page). In my developer tool in my browser I see the following warning: 1Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg. How can I fix this?

I am using cloud9ide and express 2.4.6

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(process.env.C9_PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file in question is not in JPEG format. Can you save that URL as a file using `wget`, `curl` or similar tools and open that file in a text editor?

A valid JPEG file should look like binary garbage and should have "JFIF" signature string close to the beginning (byte offset 6 I think).

it is possible that the file contains an error message instead of valid JPEG data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug from cloud9 ide. I tried my code locally and it worked. There is a ticket open on cloud9ide at: http://cloud9ide.lighthouseapp.com/projects/67519/tickets/390-get-png-image-not-working-in-preview-mode#ticket-390-4