# express.js not serving my image

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps-markers

I don't understand whats going wrong here.

directory structure:

```
app/server.js
app/public/index.html
app/public/js/main.js
app/public/img/car.png
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs') ,express = require('express'),
app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', 'utf8', function(err, text){
        res.send(text);
    });
});

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on %d', app.address().port);  
});
```

main.js

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        position:coords,
        icon: 'img/car.png'
    });
```

**erroroutput:**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/img/car.png
```

All my css files and js files load with no problem.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
This was due to the file being named car.png.png 
When browsing in windows, fileextensions were not visible so I was fooled into thinking the name was really car.png 
Lesson learned!

Comment: Are you testing this locally? A glance over similar questions in StackOverflow indicates that some cloud providers may be messing things up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506797/static-image-file-is-invisible-in-node-js-express

Comment: Yes, tested both locally and on nodejitsu with the same result.

Comment: @DavidEllis: The symptom there is different (not a 404).

Comment: Have you tried opening the ``.png`` manually? I just realized that perhaps what's happening is that Google's server can't see your image, and the error message it's returning is erroneous (shouldn't be a 404, should be a cannot connect to server).

Comment: Worth mentioning: placing an img-tag with src 'img/car.png' also crashes with a 404

Comment: Permissions on the file and the ``img`` directory are fine for the server to access them? (Can you read the file in Node.js and output it via a controller for ``img2/car.png``?)

Comment: @DavidEllis not sure what you mean with manually but yeah, the problem is not isolated to Google.

Comment: I mean, you have a controller that reads in the ``index.html`` file, so the Express server has permission to read the file. Can you double-check that you have the proper permissions on the file and directory for the image? (One way would be to write a controller to serve up image explicitly in your code.)

Comment: FWIW, just installed express, copied your `server.js`, and created the structure above (except I didn't bother with `main.js`, just had the `img` tag directly in `index.html`). Works for me. So it's not your `server.js` file. I like @David's thought re permissions, definitely worth checking that the permissions on `car.png` are okay.

Comment: Solved it, and the reason is so embarrasing I barely want to say it: the file was named car.png.png, but looking at it through windows explorer I just saw "car.png" and assumed it was right, too used to OSX I guess. Thanks for all the help though, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Change this line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

To this

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Comment: Do not use sync functions for requests reponses. They should only ever be used during app setup. Use instead `fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res)`

Comment: @DeaDEnD That's fine, but don't down vote my answer because the first part IS the solution. I know it is because I had solved the same problem literally MINUTES before I found this question. kthnxbi

Comment: @runexec: I downvoted you, because recommending `fs.readFileSync` is bad. And no, that was not the solution for OP -- turned out the file was named `car.png.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path - /img/car.png