# Serving images not working Express server

Tags: image, express, static, nodes

I have the `images` in the root folder and trying to access the file but the files couldn't be accessible. any advice is appreciated.

`app.use(express.static("images"));`

http://localhost:3000/images/16339453833951633945384807.jpg

Thank you!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813634/express-js-not-serving-my-image check this out

Answer (score 0):

assuming the file where this code lives is in the root as well, you could try:

```
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/images`));
```